# Laravel 9 error: Command "schedule:run " is not defined

Tags: php, laravel, docker, cron

I have dockerized my project and I am using cron.d to run Laravel schedules.

This is the content of my cron file:

```
* * * * * /usr/local/bin/php /var/www/artisan schedule:run
```

I even checked that there's no extra space at the end of the file.
Yet, whenever it is run, Laravel throws an error that says "schedule:run " is not a command. This is the full error:

```
[2022-08-23 08:13:06] local.ERROR: Command "schedule:run
" is not defined.
Did you mean one of these?
    schedule:clear-cache
    schedule:list
    schedule:run
    schedule:test
    schedule:work {"exception":"[object] (Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Exception\\CommandNotFoundException(code: 0): Command \"schedule:run
\" is not defined.

Did you mean one of these?
    schedule:clear-cache
    schedule:list
    schedule:run
    schedule:test
    schedule:work at /var/www/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:692)
[stacktrace]
#0 /var/www/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(259): Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Application->find()
#1 /var/www/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(171): Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Application->doRun()
#2 /var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Application.php(102): Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Application->run()
#3 /var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/Kernel.php(129): Illuminate\\Console\\Application->run()
#4 /var/www/artisan(37): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Console\\Kernel->handle()
#5 {main}
"}
```

This has been driving me crazy for hours. I have previously used the same configuration for Docker in one of my earlier projects using Laravel 7. So, it could be a Laravel 9 issue. Or is there something really obvious that I'm missing here?

Comment: you're allowed to pass strings as commands try to limit the extra space by something like `/usr/local/bin/php /var/www/artisan "schedule:run"`?

Comment: @Minato I'm not sure. I will check it and I'll let you know if it works. I decided to put a semicolon at the end of my cron command to ensure that it knows where it ends and it seems to have fixed the problem so far. I'm still waiting to see if it has fixed the issue or not.

Comment: @Minato I just checked it. Your solution seems to work as well.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest reading the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/scheduling)

so try

```
    * * * * * cd /var/www/ && php artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
```